# Когда вы переключаетесь с одного Activity на другой, нажав на кнопку, Navigation Bar появляется и исчезает. Как его убрать?

Tags: java, android

Когда вы переключаетесь с одного Activity на другой, нажав на кнопку, Navigation Bar появляется и исчезает. Как его убрать? Мне нужно, чтобы Navigation Bar появлялся только тогда, когда этого хочет пользователь. И его не было во время переходов.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    executeDelayed();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    executeDelayed();
}

private void hideSystemUI(){
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

private void executeDelayed() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Может вызывать `hideSystemUI()` напрямую, без задержки в пол секунды?

Comment: Спасибо вам! Что-то я очевидную вещь не заметил.